# How to run Ubuntu in VirtualBox more smoothly?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I speed up Ubuntu in virtual box? I've allocated 2 cores, 2gb ram, 128mb vram, 3d acceleration, installed guest additions, but it's still pretty slow. Moving windows around is really choppy, launching programs is fairly slow. It's not like my main computer's bad, the VM's just not using much cpu or ram at all. I don't know what the problem is. It runs about as good as it did on my old computer, which was much worse. I thought a far better computer would run a VM more smoothly.

Edit: I have tried running the vm with 4gb of memory assigned, but it made no difference at all, it's still choppy, and the experience was pretty identical. I'm not running games or anything, just simple things like terminal for most things. But when I want to use firefox, or something similar, or even just moving a terminal window around, it's just really sluggish and choppy.

Comment: What Ubuntu version you ran on Vbox?

Comment: @Jim I believe ubuntu 19

Answer (score 1):

If you only want 19.04 feeling (e. g. apps, repositories) I'd say go for lighter flavor like Lubuntu or Xubuntu, those will work great with only 2 GB RAM.

Ubuntu 19.04 needs more than 2 GB RAM to ran smoothly—3-4 GB is decent enough, also you can try enabling Hardware Virtualization to improve your guest OS performance.

Thus, assigning more RAM might help improve overall performance—other than that you're good to go.

Related:

[How do I improve the performance of my VirtualBox guest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190330/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-my-virtualbox-guest)

[How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox)

[How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)

[Will be Ubuntu 18.04 work fine on 2GB of RAM](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/a2eaxr/will_be_ubuntu_1804_work_fine_on_2_gb_of_ram/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out lubuntu.

Comment: I tried assigning 4gb of ram to the vm, but there was literally no difference. It's till really choppy, and just not a smooth experience at all. It's perfectly usable, just not very enjoyable to use.